# Save E-Mail like it was at Send-Time

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, automation

Because of GDPR and CRM aspects we would like to store emails like they were at send time.

Problem / tried solution:

Unfortunately the current implementation of dynamic content blocks is not able to work in View As Web Page (VAWP) when you override the sending data extension at a daily basis. It will always show default content after the automation has taken place because of the way dynamic content blocks are implemented with guide template language. [This is an gap of the product, admitted by salesforce support]. Basicly thats the reason why we cannot use the view_email_url from send-log. [Even when i would set AmpScript-Variables in messagecontext VAWP with lookups like Lookup("SendLog","field","SubID",@SubscriberID,"JobID",@JobID,"BatchID",@BatchID)]. Because of shadow data extensions in the background of journey builder this could work in journeys but we would like to have a solid implementation.

Question:

Is there a solution / automation / ampscript which can fulfill the purpose to store the email like it was at send time like a html page / pdf ...?

Comment: Have you tried inserting the html into a de? Only issue is that you will won’t be Able to store assets from the send. Alternatively Salesforce have an email archival tool but that’s comes at a cost

Comment: I haven't tried storing the whole email as html until now. How would you insert the whole html into a dataextension field? Isn't there a limit of characters for each field? What language / calls do you make to get the whole html of an email? Will the urls of pictures be valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer here :

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/203293/45908

If you remove the 'length' of a text field of a data extension then it will it's max varchar.

This solution only stores a copy of the HTML so any assets and URLs in the html may not be live in future.

Salesforce otherwise sells an archiving solution with PDF copies each email

You could also BCC an email address - but that too will cost you double your Super Messages

Comment: Do you know what the max varchar is?