# Retrieving email content via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, integration

we have connect the own-built CRM system via API to the Marketing Cloud. What we are currently trying to achieve is capturing the content of an email that has been sent to an individual customer and place it to the CRM to have it available for the sales reps. As far as we could see so far the only possibility to see the HTML of a sent email is via the Send Report under "Tracking" in Email Studio. However, if Dynamic Content Blocks are being used in an email, all the different blocks are being displayed in the email preview and hence in the code we can retrieve. Now my question, if there is any (other) possibility to retrieve the code/content of exactly the email an individual user has received? Thanks!

Comment: You may want to check this link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/194105/retrieving-html-body-of-complete-sfmc-email?rq=1