# Personalization on Thumbnail in SFDC for Individual Email Results

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, reporting, marketing-cloud-connect

We're trying to resolve what appears to be a simple ask and I've been told this is possible but can't find any documentation here or on help.sf.com.  We are sending email to subscribers using SF DEs and the data is updating in SFDC but the thumbnail does not show the personalization the recipient received nor does it show the actual fields used (instead, it shows as %%field%%).

We'd like to update our config to have these values appear in the subscriber's SFDC record.
Can someone point me in the right direction? Can we add the content in SFDC as requested above?

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Changing this behaviour to make every thumbnail resemble the actual email send is not possible, as this would require MC to generate a personalised image of every email sent. The thumbnail currently rendered is the one of the email without any personalisation applied.

My recommendation, if you want to be able to view each email sent as it looked at send time, is to store the actual HTML in a data extension. You can use [this solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/203293/36623) to fetch the content of VAWP url, and store the complete HTML of the email. It will not generate a thumbnail, but at least you will be able to render the email. Based on JobID and Subscriber Key, you can render the email in e.g. a Cloud Page.

Comment: Thanks for this.  A colleague had suggested the VAWP method but I'm trying to get this into the SF record and out of SFMC.  I guess I can use UpdateSingleSalesforceObject AMPscript in the email send and write to the record?

Comment: forgot to add...

Can we add a field to Individual Email Results then write this value into the field?  My concern is that the record won't exist in IER until after the email send completes.

Is this why an API call would be required?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the data model of IER. I will also not recommend using both HTTPGet and UpdateSingleSalesforceObject in one and same email - as it will lead to latency. My advice will be to dump it into a data extension and either expose as external object, or sync with bulk API, asynchronously.